# how to remove an image and reusing it

Tags: javascript

im trying to create a blackjack game in javascript , everything works fine with drawing cards , and stopping after it hits 21.
i've got a problem with starting a new game , i need to delete the exisited cards and display new ones
i tried to change the **display** to hidden but when i change the display to visible again all the old cards pop up as well . i tried to use **.parentNode.removeChild** but then there is a problem that the parameter is **NULL** and it cannot be used again .. how can i delete the existed and start over with the same parameter?

it's not finished yet , for now it's a draft**.

**JavaScript Code:**

```
var cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13];
var images =
    ["media/cards/AC.jpg", "media/cards/2.jpg", "media/cards/3C.jpg", "media/cards/4C.jpg",
        "media/cards/5C.jpg", "media/cards/6C.jpg", "media/cards/7C.jpg", "media/cards/8C.jpg",
        "media/cards/9C.jpg", "media/cards/10C.jpg", "media/cards/JC.jpg", "media/cards/QC.jpg",
        "media/cards/KC.jpg"
    ];
var upside = "media/cards/UpsideDown.jpg";
var Check2Cards = 0;
var Check2Cards2 = true;
var checkUserScore = 0;
var newgame;
function deal()
{
    if (Check2Cards2) {
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 13));
       
var UserCards = document.getElementById('user');
        var card = document.createElement('img');
        card.setAttribute("width", 250);
        card.setAttribute("src", images[random]);
        UserCards.appendChild(card);
        checkUserScore += cards[random];
        
        if (checkUserScore > 21) {
            Check2Cards2 = false;
            checkUserScore = 0;
            newgame = true;
        }
    }

    if (newgame == true) {
        UserCards.parentNode.removeChild(UserCards);
        
        UserCards.parentNode.appendChild(UserCards);
    }
    
        
    Check2Cards2 = true;
    newgame = false;
            
}
```

**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    <!--<link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
        .show {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(media/background5.jpg);background-size:100%;text-align:center">
    <center>
        <table border="1" width="100%" height="100%" style="text-align: center">
            <tr><td style="height:300pt;width:100%;font-size:100pt;color:white"><p id="dealer">TOP</p></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="height:400pt;width:50%;font-size:100pt;color:white;float:left">left</td><td style="height:400pt;width:49%;font-size:100pt;color:white;float:right"><button style="font-size:100pt" id="deal" onclick="deal()">deal</button></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="height:350pt;width:100%;font-size:100pt;color:white"><div id="user" ></div></td></tr>
        </table>
        <!--<img id="img2" src="media/cards/2.jpg"onclick="document.getElementById('img2').className='hidden'"/>-->
      
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just clear innerHTML: `if (newgame === true) UserCards.innerHTML = ""; `

Answer (score 0):

Just do as @Kinglish suggested

```
if (newgame == true) {
    UserCards.innerHtml = "";
}
```

Or remove the cards one by one

```
if (newgame == true) {
   while(UserCards.firstChild){
       UserCards.removeChild(UserCards.firstChild);
   }
}
```

Comment: it works , but do the hidden images take space somewhere? will it slow down the game at some point? thanks alot

Comment: It removes the content of the usercards. You cannot find them anywhere, you should use another method if you want to store them. However, it's not best practice to store your game history on the frontend

Comment: sorry , i dont know what is frontend i'm new to javascript . this is my first time im building a game , please give me tips how to improve my code

Comment: You will learn it step by step, begin by using let and const instead of var